# When one asset doesn't load, this should NOT interfere with other assets (all over CDN)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, assets, cdn, cloudinary

On a page, I have links to multiple assets via CDN and also am using Cloudinary to manipulate my image files. So in other words, the code looks like this:

```
<%= cl_image_tag "Logo white.png" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://something.css' %>
```

Recently, I noticed that the `css` link was broken, but the fact that it was broken interfered with Cloudinary so that the image could not be loaded. Is there a way to prevent this kind of behavior? Something that ensures that even if some assets don't load, other things run?

Comment: What kind of failure (e.g. error message) do you see? A client-side 404 error shouldn't affect image loading. Do you see any related server-side error?

Comment: Oh you know what I think I figured out why. The client-side 404 affected the JS, since I had scripts that required the asset to run (js asset and css asset, not just css as the code example shows). That probably would have affected Cloudinary right? There were no server side issues

Comment: The Cloudinary code that shows on your example runs in the server side and renders as regular HTML <img> tag -  which shouldn't be affected by JS nor by CSS AFAICS. Did you try fixing the CSS link? Did it solve the issue?

Comment: Then that's very weird... fixing the css/ js broken links solved the issue